# How do I setup Ubuntu interfaces so one interface is "mapped" to another?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dhcp, dhcp-server

I have recently setup a DHCP-Server on an Ubuntu 10.04 server machine. The machine has two interfaces (eth0, eth1). I have the DHCP server setup correctly because computers connecting to the network get a DHCP IP address but they cannot connect to the outside world.

I believe it has to do with the two interfaces being mapped/bridged together. How do I properly map one interface to the other? Is it bridging or mapping?

I see on this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dhcp3-server they do something like

```
mapping hotplug
    script grep
    map eth1
```

What does that exactly do?

In other places I see the following:

```
iface br0 inet static
bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

Which is better or more efficient?

Sorry for all the questions, I'm a noob at setting up a DCHP Server.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

This question is in relation to a previous question I asked on ServerFault: [Is it possible to setup a DHCP Server for localhost only?](https://serverfault.com/questions/323051/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-dhcp-server-for-localhost-only).

Basically I want to setup one interface (eth0) to connect to the outside world while (eth1) listens for DHCP requests from the VM's (bridged network setting in VMWare). It's setup on a server and the VM's are properly getting the DHCP IP's but they cannot see the outside world. :(

I used the configuration files from this post as a baseline to setup DHCP http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=825294 (only difference we have 2 interfaces while they have 3) but unfortunately they didn't share their interfaces setup and its an old post.

Comment: What are the two interfaces connected to? What are you using two interfaces for? (For load distribution? For redundancy? To connect to two different networks?)

Comment: While they might be getting an IP address, are they getting the correct gateway assigned?

Comment: Hey David/Justin, thanks for your speedy response. I've updated the post with more details.

Comment: Have you set up NAT? If you're giving the VMs local IPs, they won't be able to talk to the outside world without [masquerading](http://linux.about.com/od/ubusrv_doc/a/ubusg18t03.htm).

Answer (score 0):

To setup masquerading quickly (and add firewalling) install the `shorewall-perl` package.  Use the two-interface configuration from `/usr/share/doc/shorewall/examples/two-interfaces` to get started.

It expects the Internet to be on the eth0 interface.  Your DHCP server should be handling eth1.  The [Shorewall](http://shorewall.net/) site has lots of documentation.  You can install the `shorewall-doc` package to get a local copy of the documentation.